# Show that the set of unions of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ is a topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Let $U=\{(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\tau=\{\bigcup X\mid X\subseteq U\}$. I want to show that $\tau$ is a topology. Here's the small bit I have. Please let me know mistakes and steps I'm missing. (or even a completely alternative proof).

1- Since $\varnothing \subset U$, then $\varnothing \in \tau$ (is this enough to show this?). How can I show that $\mathbb{R}\in \tau$? It seems to me that $\mathbb{R}\in U$, but how do you show that some interval in $U$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

2- To show $\forall_{A,B\in \tau}A\cap B\in \tau$: For $X_1,X_2\subset U$ let $X_3=\{x_1\cap x_2\mid x_1\in X_1\wedge x_2\in X_2\}$ which is a subset of $U$ since intersection of two intervals is an interval. Then we have $(\bigcup X_1)\cap(\bigcup X_2)=\bigcup X_3 \in \tau$.

3- How do I show the union of any subset of $\tau$ is in $\tau$? $\forall_{A\subseteq\tau} \bigcup(A)\in \tau $

Comment: Did you mean $X\in U$ where you wrote $X\subseteq U$ on the first line?  To show $\mathbb R\in\tau,$ you could say $$\mathbb R=\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} (n-1,n+1)$$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I wanted $X$ to be a set of intervals so $X\subseteq U$. In other words $X\in \mathcal P(U)$.
 Do you mean $\mathbb R=\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z} (n-1,n+1)$?
Intuitively, I see that the union gives $\mathbb R$, how do you prove this though? (sorry if it's an elementary question!)

Comment: Yes, I meant $n\in \mathbb Z$.  Good question.  For all $x\in\mathbb R$, $x\in(n-1,n+1)$ where  $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$, which exists because of the Archimedean property of $\mathbb R$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! This shows $\mathbb R\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(n-1,n+1)$. Do we need to also show $x\in \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(n-1,n+1)\rightarrow x\in\mathbb R$? Can we say from definition of union, $\exists k (x\in(k-1,k+1))$ so $x\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: $\emptyset$ is the union of an empty set of intervals, so is in the topology.

Comment: @Ali:  since $(n-1,n+1)\subseteq \mathbb R$ for all $n$, also $\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z} (n-1,n+1)\subseteq \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and $\tau$ is the usual euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$.

$(1)$ Yes, but as user3482749 noted $\Bbb R\notin U$. $\bigcup\emptyset=\emptyset\in\tau$ and as J.W. Tanner pointed out $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{a>0}(-a,a)$.

$(2)$ Yes.

$(3)$ Let $\mathcal A\subseteq\tau$ be non-empty. For each $A\in\mathcal A$ we can choose $I_A\subseteq U$ such that $A=\bigcup I_A$. Therefore, $\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A} I_A\subseteq U$ and $\bigcup\mathcal A=\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A}\bigcup I_A=\bigcup\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal A} I_A\in\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $\mathbb{R}$ is not in $U$: what would be the $a$ and $b$? However, note that $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of $(-n,n)$ for all natural $n$, and each of those is in $U$, hence $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\tau$.

Part 2 you've already done.

For part 3: If $\sigma \subseteq \tau$, then for all $A \in \sigma$, there is $\mu_A \subseteq U$ such that $$A = \bigcup\limits_{B \in \mu_A}B,$$ since also $A \in \tau$.

But then, $$\bigcup\limits_{A \in \sigma}A = \bigcup\limits_{A\in\sigma}\bigcup\limits_{B\in\mu_A}B,$$ and since each $B \in U$, this is a union of intervals, so we're done.